# Can I mix c and cpp files in a C++ project?

Tags: c++, c, linker

I have a project that had c files and cpp files mixed in it. The linker throws errors at me:

```
undefined reference to <all my functions in the c files>
```

After I rename all `*.c` files to `*.cpp` the errors vanish. So can't I mix those files or is this some compiler/linker options problem?

---

**My options:**

**GCC C++ Compiler:**

```
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I"/myPath" -O0 -g3   \
    -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 gtk+-2.0
```

**GCC C Compiler:**

```
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I"/myPath" -O0 -g3   \
    -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 gtk+-2.0`
```

**GCC C++ Linker:**

```
-L/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

---

Since it says C++ Linker, does that mean object files from c files cannot be linked into the project (by default)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`extern "C"` is one approach. The other approach, assuming your C files are of the (almost ubiquitous) sort which are already compilable as C++, is simply to coerce the compiler into treating them as C++ (which gives them the appropriate name mangling to work with your C++ files). For GCC, this is `-x c++`.

Comment: This looks like a better solution, doesn't it ? (since I don't have to pollute the code with wrappers), [more reference](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options)

Comment: It depends. I say "almost ubiquitous" but there is the odd C library which has a variable named `class`... and it doesn't work for precompiled C libraries. But yeah, when it works, there's way fewer gotchas than with `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 15):

You need to *wrap* the C code like so

```
extern "C" {
    #include "sample1.h"
}
```

A better way to do it is like in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789340/combining-c-and-c-how-does-ifdef-cplusplus-work), in the C header files.

use:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

At the start of **all C header files**.

and use:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

At the end of **all C header files**.

Comment: Well, in most cases this will work, but it's a bit of a kludge. It's better to carefully place the `extern "C"`s inside the header, either creating a new header for `C++` use, or detecting when you are being compiled as `C++` as described in [the question you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3789340/1171191).

Comment: @BoBTFish You and I have both linked to the same question. See the second link I posted.

Comment: I will rephrase and fix though, better make it clear.

Comment: Man, it's so hard to begin coding in C/C++ nowadays :-( Thank you, this solves a lot of problems.

Comment: @mini-me Are you implying that it was easier before?

Comment: Yes, it was easier before. C# and other nice languages make us lazy.

Comment: @mini-me: actually, it's *incredibly simple* compared to mixing say... Python and C. Mixing languages in general is **hard**, there are only few cases where people worked on a FFI (Foreign Function Interface), which in general is just "whatever" interacting with C.